# Flash builder 4 - change output filename using external build-config.xml (not Ant)

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, config

I'm trying to change the output filename with a config file loaded via the compiler option -load-config. It looks like this in my compiler arguments:

```
-load-config+=build-config.xml.
```

I've tried the following:

```
<flex-config>
    <o>absolute/path/to/filename</o>
</flex-config>
```

and

```
<flex-config>
    <output>absolute/path/to/filename</output>
</flex-config>
```

and

```
<flex-config>
    <compiler>
        <o>absolute/path/to/filename</o>
    </compiler>
</flex-config>
```

and

```
<flex-config>
    <compiler>
        <output>absolute/path/to/filename</output>
    </compiler>
</flex-config>
```

but none have worked. I'm on a PC using Flash Builder 4. Has anyone else done this? Also, ideally, I want to use a relative path instead of absolute. I can't get this to work either, even if I do so in the "additional compiler arguments" field of the Project configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I use ANT build files for deploy and I just live with ClassName.swf for debug

Answer (score 0):

You were close :)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<flex-config>
    <compiler>
        ...
    </compiler>
    <!-- Needs to be outside of compiler tag -->
    <output>bin/swf/MyApp.swf</output>
</flex-config>
```